# capistrano errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

After executing

```
cap deploy:setup
```

I get this error

```
failed: "sh -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' mkdir -p /u/apps/blog /u/apps/blog/releases /u/apps/blog/shared /u/apps/blog/shared/system /u/apps/blog/shared/log /u/apps/blog/shared/pids'" on foobar.com
```

Here is the content of my deploy.rb

```
require 'capistrano'


    # Account Settings
    set :user, "user"
    set :password, "pass"
    set :domain, "foobar.com"
    set :mount_path, "/"
    set :application, "blog"

    set :repository, "/Users/me/Desktop/project"
    set :local_repository, "/Users/me/Desktop/project"
    set :scm, :git
    set :deploy_via, :copy

    role :app, 'foobar.com'
role :web, 'foobar.com'
```

What could be the problem ?

//EDIT

```
*** [err :: foobar.com] stdin: is not a tty
*** [err :: foobar.com] sudo:
*** [err :: foobar.com] can't mkdir /var/db/sudo: No such file or directory
*** [err :: foobar.com] sudo:
*** [err :: foobar.com] no tty present and no askpass program specified
failed: "sh -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' mkdir -p /u/apps/blog /u/apps/blog/releases /u/apps/blog/shared /u/apps/blog/shared/system /u/apps/blog/shared/log /u/apps/blog/shared/pids'" on foobar.com
```

Comment: Run it verbose with `cap -v deploy:setup`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add this line to your `deploy.rb` (for example after `set :application, "blog"`)

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

And now run:

```
cap -v deploy:setup
```

---

If you don't have sudo privileges add this line to `deploy.rb`:

```
set :use_sudo, false
```

You must have permissions to create `/u/apps/blog` directory or change deploy folder with:

```
set :deploy_to, "/home/user_name/apps/blog"
```

Comment: Already did that but looks like capistrano want sudo access. But I don't have a such.

Comment: I get mkdir: cannot create directory `/u': Permission denied

Comment: add this line `set :deploy_to, "/home/youtuser/apps/blog"`

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! The `set :deploy_to` line is missing in Webfaction's documentation. Added that in and it works like a charm.

Comment: I was getting the same error because - `set :application, "blog"` and `set :deploy_to, "/home/youtuser/apps/blog"` where not same, meaning i was using a different name instead of application name in `:deploy_to`

Comment: This no longer works in Capistrano 3 as the `:use_sudo` config option has been removed. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21336645/83743 for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, true
```