# Capistrano 3 sudo task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I want to write a recipe with Capistrano 3 executing a task on the remote server with sudo.

With Capistrano 2 this could be done for example:

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true

task :hello do
  run "#{sudo} cp ~/something /something"
end
```

With Capistrano 3 I found:

```
set :pty, true
```

But I could not get to execute a task running with sudo.

How can I run a task with sudo?

Comment: @Rubyman `:use_sudo` is not a valid setting for Capistrano 3. See this [related ticket](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/920)

Answer (score 21):

The Capistrano 3 guide recommends the use of passwordless sudo. This allows your less-priveleged user execute the sudo command without having to enter a password via the PTY.

You can use the task that Kentaro wrote above, and add something like the following to your /etc/sudoers file:

```
deploy ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/cp ~/something /something
```

http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#toc_8

Comment: And if  your policies dictate that you must use a password?

Answer (score 19):

I usually write like this:

```
task :hello do
  on roles(:all) do |host|
    execute :sudo, :cp, '~/something', '/something'
  end
end
```

---

**Edit**

Capistrano 3 does not support sudo with password.

However, I created a small [gem](https://github.com/kentaroi/sshkit-sudo), which enables you to use sudo with password in Capistrano 3 task.

Add [sshkit-sudo](https://github.com/kentaroi/sshkit-sudo) to your application's Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'sshkit-sudo'
```

And require 'sshkit/sudo' in you Capfile:

```
# Capfile
require 'sshkit/sudo'
```

Now, you can execute a command with sudo as follows:

```
task :hello do
  on roles(:all) do
    sudo :cp, '~/something', '/something'
  end
end
```

Comment: I already tried this to. The console displays this:                INFO [5d8e920e] Running /usr/bin/env sudo cp ~/something /something on example.local
DEBUG [5d8e920e] Command: /usr/bin/env sudo cp ~/something /something
DEBUG [5d8e920e]  [sudo] password for main:                   I can also insert my password, which is displayed by the way, but the task does not continue on return.

Comment: If you really want to use sudo with password, you should use capistrano 2.

Comment: This works. Thanks. If someone is looking to do apt-ge with sshkit-sudo try `sudo :'apt-get', '-y install curl'`

Comment: `sudo` instead of `execute` did the job for me. thx

Answer (score 15):

To resolve this issue I needed to add `set :pty, true` to my `deploy.rb` file.

I can now run the following:

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.1.0'

set :application, 'APP_NAME'
set :pty, true
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart NGINX'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 1 do
       execute :sudo, "./restart.sh"
    end
  end

end
```

This task basically runs a shell script called `restart.sh` that has a command within `sudo service nginx restart`.

Comment: Yes, only after setting `set :pty, true` can you execute sudo commands with capistrano 3. Otherwise you will get `sudo stderr: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` errors.

Comment: When I do this it asks me for my password, but I cannot "enter" it, it just gives me newlines..

Comment: @TimBaas were you able to solve your issue ? I am also stuck with the same problem

Comment: @aelor did you solve that problem, I'm stuck in the same place

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh @aelor - make sure you've added `set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}`

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh basically the log that you are seeing is not an interactive shell. So you cannot input anything. Now, to solve this, you can do either of two things: a) add your user to with no password access inside sudoers file or b) do a `bundle install --deployment`, the deployment flag makes sure that the gems get installed within the vendor directory for which the user already has access. The latter solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

you want "as user do end", like

```
as "root" do
  execute :something
end
```

Comment: I think this is the Capistrano 2.x syntax?

Comment: AFAIK as-user-do is a new cap 3 construct. I could be wrong but I have been using cap since its infancy and cannot recall ever seeing this construct until the newer version. But- my memory is certainly fallible.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use `sudo` you can always map the command like `SSHKit.config.command_map[:rm] = 'sudo rm'` which will make `execute :rm` into the proper `rm` command invoked with `sudo`. If your deploy user is in the sudoers things will work as expected.